# Automated test fails on button click

Tags: java, ios, testing, intellij-idea, appium

I downloaded a simple app from appium github  and tried to write an automated test for it using Appium Server (version 1.3.3). Here is my code

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;

public class AppiumDemo {

    private AppiumDriver ad;

    @Before
    public void setupTest(){
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.3.3");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 5s");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/admin/Downloads/TestApp.app");
        try {
            ad = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        if(ad != null) ad.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void main() {
        ad.findElement(By.name("IntegerA")).sendKeys("11");
        ad.findElement(By.name("IntegerB")).sendKeys("1");
        ad.findElement(By.name("ComputeSumButton")).click();
        int ans = Integer.parseInt(ad.findElement(By.name("Answer")).getText());
        assertEquals(ans, 12);
        ad.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

it opens the simulator, enters 2 numbers, but when should click on the button to calculate the sum, test crashes, simulator is killed. in intellij it shows that it failed on the line I press click. and - Process finished with exit code 255.
I use Yosemite , v. 10.10.1 installed on wmware.
Please help me, what can be the reason of it ? thanks a lot.

**here is interesting parts of my Appium log**

```
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:27 +0000 Debug: Got new command 3 from instruments: au.getElementByName('IntegerA')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:27 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElementByName('IntegerA')
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:27 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] Socket data received (38 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0"}}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0"},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element 200 371.561 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0"},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:27 Admins-Mac.local lsd[3625] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Currently 0 installed placeholders: (
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] )
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element/0/value {"id":"0","value":["11"]}
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElement('0').setValueByType('11')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElement('0').setValueByType('11')
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:27 +0000 Debug: Lookup returned [object UIATextField] with the name "IntegerA" (id: 0).
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:27 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:27 +0000 Debug: Running system command #4: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0"}}...

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:28 +0000 Debug: Got new command 4 from instruments: au.getElement('0').setValueByType('11')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:28 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElement('0').setValueByType('11')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:28 +0000 Debug: UIATextField.tap()

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:28 Admins-Mac.local backboardd[3609] <Error>: HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'ScriptAgent' access to protected services is denied.

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:29 +0000 Debug: UIATextField.tap()

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:31 Admins-Mac.local calaccessd[3653] <Notice>: 2014-12-29 16:03:31.354|3653|0x103c48c80: Updating birthday calendar
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:31 Admins-Mac.local calaccessd[3653] <Notice>: 2014-12-29 16:03:31.356|3653|0x103c48c80: BirthdayCal: Processing 6 people...
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:31 Admins-Mac.local calaccessd[3653] <Notice>: 2014-12-29 16:03:31.418|3653|0x103c48c80: BirthdayCal: Done. 4 adds, 0 updates, 0 deletes.

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:31 Admins-Mac.local SpringBoard[3619] <Notice>: 2014-12-29 16:03:31.429|3619|0x117839a40: Region monitoring not available or enabled. Trigger ignored!

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:31 Admins-Mac.local mobileassetd[3656] <Error>: Could not copy XPC event for stream/key: com.apple.xpc.activity/com.apple.mobileassetd.queued-asset-download: 3: No such process

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:31 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("1")

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:33 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("1")

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:33 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:33 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}

info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element/0/value 200 6311.176 ms - 74 {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element {"using":"name","value":"IntegerB"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElementByName('IntegerB')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementByName('IntegerB')
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:33 +0000 Debug: Running system command #5: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:34 +0000 Debug: Got new command 5 from instruments: au.getElementByName('IntegerB')
       2014-12-29 12:03:34 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElementByName('IntegerB')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:34 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:34 +0000 Debug: Lookup returned [object UIATextField] with the name "IntegerB" (id: 1).
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:34 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:34 +0000 Debug: Running system command #6: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"}}...
info: [debug] Socket data received (38 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"}}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element 200 298.653 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element/1/value {"id":"1","value":["1"]}
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElement('1').setValueByType('1')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElement('1').setValueByType('1')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:35 +0000 Debug: Got new command 6 from instruments: au.getElement('1').setValueByType('1')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:35 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElement('1').setValueByType('1')
       2014-12-29 12:03:35 +0000 Debug: UIATextField.tap()

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:35 +0000 Debug: target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("1")

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:36 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished

info: [debug] Socket data received (25 bytes)

info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":""}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element/1/value 200 1962.511 ms - 74 {"status":0,"value":"","sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element {"using":"name","value":"ComputeSumButton"}
info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElementByName('ComputeSumButton')"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElementByName('ComputeSumButton')
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:36 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:36 +0000 Debug: Running system command #7: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":""}...

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:37 +0000 Debug: Got new command 7 from instruments: au.getElementByName('ComputeSumButton')
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:37 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElementByName('ComputeSumButton')

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:37 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:37 +0000 Debug: Lookup returned [object UIAButton] with the name "ComputeSumButton" (id: 2).
       2014-12-29 12:03:37 +0000 Debug: responding with:
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:37 +0000 Debug: Running system command #8: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"}}...

info: [debug] Socket data received (38 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"}}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element 200 833.732 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element/2/click {"id":"2"}
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElement('2').rect()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElement('2').rect()

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:38 +0000 Debug: Got new command 8 from instruments: au.getElement('2').rect()
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:38 +0000 Debug: evaluating au.getElement('2').rect()

info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:38 +0000 Debug: evaluation finished
       2014-12-29 12:03:38 +0000 Debug: responding with:

info: [debug] Socket data received (83 bytes)
info: [debug] Socket data being routed.
info: [debug] Got result from instruments: {"status":0,"value":{"origin":{"x":94,"y":122},"size":{"width":113,"height":37}}}
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED)","code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","origValue":"connect ECONNREFUSED"},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb/element/2/click 500 1022.219 ms - 293 
info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.3","revision":"34e21b01b87d4e3959e1c97c0a8d0b1a610bdc78"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.537 ms - 178 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.3.3","revision":"34e21b01b87d4e3959e1c97c0a8d0b1a610bdc78"},"isShuttingDown":false},"sessionId":"b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb"}

info: --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/b488504c-fada-4d13-801b-67ddfda7fcfb {}
info: Shutting down appium session
info: [debug] Stopping ios
info: [debug] Destroying instruments client socket.
info: [debug] Closing socket server.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server was closed
info: [debug] Sending sigterm to instruments
info: [debug] [INST] 2014-12-29 12:03:38 +0000 Debug: Running system command #9: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js /tmp/instruments_sock 2,{"status":0,"value":{"origin":{"x":94,"y":122},"size":{"width":113,"height":37}}}...
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:38 Admins-Mac.local mstreamd[3614] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:38 Admins-Mac.local mstreamd[3614] <Notice>: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x103b14220>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Dec 29 16:03:38 Admins-Mac.local mstreamd[3614] <Notice>: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.

info: [debug] Instruments didn't terminate after 3 seconds; trying to kill it

info: [debug] Killall instruments

info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture

info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
```

**here is my intelliJ log**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.02 seconds
Build info: version: '2.42.1', revision: '68b415adb11acca4286be45124325cc36cfc4a51', time: '2014-05-29 09:21:55'
System info: host: 'Admins-Mac.local', ip: '192.168.0.178', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.10.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Session ID: 6da466a5-3e93-4c32-9e33-306931e05035
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
Capabilities [{platformVersion=7.1, app=/Users/admin/Downloads/TestApp.app, platform=MAC, databaseEnabled=false, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceName=iPhone 5s, platformName=iOS, browserName=iOS, appium-version=1.3.3, webStorageEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, desired={platformVersion=7.1, app=/Users/admin/Downloads/TestApp.app, platformName=iOS, deviceName=iPhone 5s, appium-version=1.3.3}, locationContextEnabled=false, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at AppiumDemo.simpleTest(AppiumDemo.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: Can you provide logs to further understand the crashing scenario

Comment: I just added it in my post.

Comment: That's the intelliJ logs. Can you provide the Appium logs?

Comment: I added important parts, maybe more than that. hope it will hint anything ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this case!
Appium supports WebDriver API, so maybe because of it default elements are web elements. and so web elements don't have tap, but have click, and mobile elements have tap, not click.
in our case, every element should be declared as mobile element. so if I declare my button as Mobile element, it will have the tap fuction. :)

```
MobileElement btn = (MobileElement) ad.findElement(By.name("ComputeSumButton"));
    ...
btn.tap(1,1);
```